# Stacked horizontal bar plot in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I am trying to plot two sets of data as a stacked bar plot horizontally. leftLeaf data looks like this:

```
    position row
1   3.000000   1
2   8.871825   2
3   9.000000   3
4   9.350125   4
5  10.042200   5
6  10.000000   6
7   8.833650   7
```

and then I performed this to get my second dataset:

```
v1<-leftLeaf$position-8
```

where v1 looks like:

```
[1] -8.000000 -3.000000 -1.410650  0.350125  1.042200  0.602175
 [7] -1.166350
```

Then I attempted to plot this by:

```
 barplot(table(v1,leftLeaf$position), main="plot", horiz = TRUE, names.arg = leftLeaf$row, col=c("white","red"))
```

However I get this error:

```
Error in barplot.default(table(v1, leftLeaf$position), main = "plot",  : 
  incorrect number of names
```

Since the name are coming from the same dataframe as the values are, I don't understand why this is the error.

Comment: @goglian, sorry I did not get the same error using your code, I was able to produce a grpah with stacked red and white bar

Comment: @goglian, BTW your v1 values are not corresponding to the output of `leftLeaf$position - 5`